# How to override all blueprint find actions in sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I would like some code to run whenever the blueprint find action is called, regardless of the model. There are three ways I can think do this, none of which I can figure out how to implement.

1. Override all Blueprint find actions. In theory, in my routes I'd like to something like `get * overridingController.find`. The from within this function do my stuff and then call the blueprint find hook.
2. Use middleware which runs *after* the controller's action. I don't see that sails has middleware which can run after an action and modify the response.
3. Trigger a function to run on an event, e.g. blueprint.find or res.send. I don't see events for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For googlers, I solved this with a policy. I still would like to find a way to run something *after* the blueprint action.

```
module.exports = async function (req, res, proceed) {
    if (req.options.model && /\/find$/.test(req.options.action)) {
        // do stuff 
        proceed(); // if you want to
    } else {
        proceed();
    }
};
```